# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS aufs errors and segfaults following system upgrade

Tags: 16.04, apt, docker

I have a bunch of hosts running docker-ce with aufs storage driver.

Yesterday I executed a full system upgrade like every month.
Here are some details of the current installation:

```
# uname -m
x86_64

# uname -r
4.4.0-142-generic

# uname -r
4.4.0-142-generic
# cat /etc/os-release 
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="16.04.6 LTS (Xenial Xerus)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS"
VERSION_ID="16.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
VERSION_CODENAME=xenial
UBUNTU_CODENAME=xenial

# dpkg -l | grep docker
ii  docker-ce                           5:18.09.3~3-0~ubuntu-xenial                amd64        Docker: the open-source application container engine
ii  docker-ce-cli                       5:18.09.3~3-0~ubuntu-xenial                amd64        Docker CLI: the open-source application container engine

# dpkg -l | grep aufs-tools
ii  aufs-tools                          1:3.2+20130722-1.1ubuntu1                  amd64        Tools to manage aufs filesystems
```

Following are the logs that raised my concern:

> dmesg

```
aufs au_opts_verify:1597:dockerd[2482]: dirperm1 breaks the protection by the permission bits on the lower branch
```

> syslog

```
Mar 13 23:05:22 <substitute-hostname> kernel: [563907.870940] auplink[1474]: segfault at 7ffd32a4f3c8 ip 00007f1217f015b9 sp 00007ffd32a4f3d0 error 6 in libc-2.23.so[7f1217e08000+1c0000]
Mar 13 23:05:22 <substitute-hostname> dockerd[11803]: time="2019-03-13T23:05:22.579109024Z" level=warning msg="Couldn't run auplink before unmount /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/c8b0987475f721a493fd325b78082432486d9bfb231fe1ef1d637cd6837374d8" error="signal: segmentation fault (core dumped)" storage-driver=aufs
```

Using a search engine, it seems to point toward an AUFS old bug, but I don't know for sure. There is also mention of an incompatible kernel version.

Does anyone has a clue on how to fix this? Or is it an active bug that I should report to Canonical?

I would really appreciate some help on this topic

Louis